# User Object - Lastvieweddate & lastreferenceddate

Tags: user, object

Referring to the User object in particular, what exactly do the fields `lastvieweddate` and `lastreferenceddate` refer to? Is the `lastvieweddate` the last time the user viewed his/her own user information and `lastreferenceddate` is the last time a user is referenced in things like changes to his/her profile or role? Or does `lastreferenceddate` track any user activity within salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

`LastViewedDate` is the timestamp for when the current user last viewed *this record*. If this value is null, this record might only have been referenced (`LastReferencedDate`) and not viewed.

`LastReferencedDate` is the timestamp for when the current user last viewed *a record related* to this record.

The distinction is viewing *this record* versus viewing *a record related* to this record. **Referenced can be any record which has a look up this record.**

More on the [User Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm).

As per documentation:

> A record is considered viewed when the user sees the details
>   associated with it, but not when the user sees it in a list with other
>   records.